# Filter range in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to filter a range in LibreOffice? For example, I have the following table.

```
Model | Type     | Size   |Price
--------------------------------
T-1   | T-Shirt  | Small  | 10
T-2   | T-Shirt  | Large  | 25
T-3   | T-Shirt  | Small  | 30
T-4   | T-Shirt  | Large  | 35
S-1   | Shirt    | Small  | 20
S-2   | Shirt    | Large  | 25
S-3   | Shirt    | Large  | 35
--------------------------------
```

I want to filter the rows with `Type=T-Shirt` and get a subtotal grouped by Size. I am looking for the LibreOffice equivalent of the following SQL query

```
SELECT Size, SUM(Price) FROM table WHERE Type = 'T-Shirt' GROUP BY Size.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a pivot table:

- Select the data
- From the menu, pick Insert | Pivot Table | Current Selection

[image]

- On the Layout window, drag `Model` and `Type` from the `Available Fields` to the `Page Fields`, `Size` to `Rows Fields`, and `Price` to the `Data Fields`.
- Click on `Options` at the bottom and select `Add Filter`.

[image]

- That will produce the pivot table with selectable filters.  Select `T-Shirt` on the filter and you have your result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did check pivot table before, but overlooked the `Add filter` option.